# Threadscope-like processor viewer/debugger for Erlang?

Tags: haskell, erlang, multicore, parallel-processing

Is there anything similar to [Threadscope](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/threadscope/) for Erlang?
Something to view how the workload is distributed across the cores, spot bottlenecks etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for [Percept](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/percept/percept_ug.html), which is part of the standard Erlang/OTP distribution.

Comment: if I am no mistaken,percept graphs (like this http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/percept/percept_overview.gif) display the number of active processes but nothing about which of them are actually running in each core, right? i'll read more about it anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's often more interesting to know the utilization and saturation of the complete system, and Percept will help you with that.